# Obtaining length of list as a value in dictionary in Python 2.7

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have two lists and dictionary as follows:

```
>>> var1=[1,2,3,4]
>>> var2=[5,6,7]
>>> dict={1:var1,2:var2}
```

I want to find the size of the mutable element from my dictionary i.e. the length of the value for a key.
After looking up the `help('dict')`, I could only find the function to return number of keys i.e. `dict.__len__()`.
I tried the Java method(hoping that it could work) i.e. `len(dict.items()[0])` but it evaluated to `2`.

I intend to find this:
Length of value for first key: `4`
Length of value for second key: `3`

when the lists are a part of the dictionary and not as individual lists in case their length is `len(list)`.

Any suggestions will be of great help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`dict.items()` is a list containing all key/value-tuples of the dictionary, e.g.:

```
[(1, [1,2,3,4]), (2, [5,6,7])]
```

So if you write `len(dict.items()[0])`, then you ask for the length of the first tuple of that items-list. Since the tuples of dictionaries are always 2-tuples (pairs), you get the length `2`. If you want the length of a value for a given key, then write:

```
len(dict[key])
```

Aso: Try not to use the names of standard types (like `str`, `dict`, `set` etc.) as variable names. Python does not complain, but it hides the type names and may result in unexpected behaviour.

Comment: In Python 3.6.3 (and probably other 3.x versions) the above solution does not work. You would have to write:

`len(list(dict.items())[0])`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using a [dict comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), for example:

```
>>> var1 = [1,2,3,4]
>>> var2 = [5,6,7]
>>> d = {1:var1, 2:var2}
>>> lengths = {key:len(value) for key,value in d.iteritems()}
>>> lengths
{1: 4, 2: 3}
```

Your "Java" method would also nearly have worked, by the way (but is rather unpythonic). You just used the wrong index:

```
>>> d.items()
[(1, [1, 2, 3, 4]), (2, [5, 6, 7])]
>>> d.items()[0]
(1, [1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> len(d.items()[0][1])
4
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>>for k,v in dict.iteritems():
   k,len(v)
```

### ans:-

```
(1, 4)
(2, 3)
```

or

```
>>>var1=[1,2,3,4]
>>>var2=[5,6,7]
>>>dict={1:var1,2:var2}
```

### ans:-

```
>>>[len(v) for k,v in dict.iteritems()]
[4, 3]
```

Comment: Note that this could've also returned `[3, 4]` as output as well( dicts don't have any specific order). So, it's better to add some explanation otherwise it may confuse the OP further.